# Triangle always says equilateral in java

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, geometry

I don't know what's wrong but my output determines that the triangle has sides 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 and is always equilateral.

```
public class Triangle
{
    // fields
    private double side1;

    private double side2;

    private double side3;

    // constructor
    public Triangle (double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        sideA = side1;
            sideB = side2;
            sideC = side3;

            if(isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC) == false)
            {
                side1 = 1;
                side2 = 1;
                side3 = 1;
            }
    }

    // methods
    public double getSide1()
    {
        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2()
    {
        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3()
    {
        return side3;
    }

    public boolean isTriangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        if (side1 + side2 > side3 || side2 + side3 > side1 || side3 + side1 > side2)
        {
                return true;
        }

        else
        {
                return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean isEquilateral()
    {
        if(side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
        {
                return true;
        }

        else
        {
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRight()
    {
        if (Math.pow (side1, 2) +  Math.pow (side2, 2) == Math.pow (side3, 2) ||
            Math.pow (side2, 2) +  Math.pow (side3, 2) == Math.pow (side1, 2) ||
            Math.pow (side3, 2) +  Math.pow (side1, 2) == Math.pow (side2, 2))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// A06 Triangle
import java.util.Scanner;

public class triangleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            double side1 = 0;
            double side2 = 0;
            double side3 = 0;

            System.out.print("Side1: ");
            side1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Side2: ");
            side2 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Side3: ");
            side3 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();

            Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);

            System.out.printf("Triangle( %.1f %.1f %.1f) %s\n", myTriangle.getSide1(),
            myTriangle.getSide2(), myTriangle.getSide3(), 
            myTriangle.isEquilateral() == true ? "is equilateral" :
            myTriangle.isRight() == true ? "is right" : "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing `double` values with `==` is not a good approach unless you plan to use just exact values (and in any case won't be suitable for `Math.pow(..) == Math.pow(..)`)

Comment: Instead of `if(condition) return true; else return false;` you can simply write `return condition;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one major error in your code:

Inside the `Triangle.java` constructor, you are assigning the input arguments to the fields, instead of the fields to the input arguments.

```
sideA = side1;
sideB = side2;
sideC = side3;
```

I think you meant to do:

```
side1 = sideA;
side2 = sideB;
side3 = sideC;
```

The other thing that will probably bite you later if not yet, is the floating point comparison, as mentioned in the comments by others. You want to change all comparisons that look like this:

```
Math.pow (side1, 2) +  Math.pow (side2, 2) == Math.pow (side3, 2)
```

to comparisons that look like this:

```
Math.abs(Math.pow (side1, 2) +  Math.pow (side2, 2) - Math.pow (side3, 2)) < EPSILON
```

where you can define `EPSILON` as some very small constant, such as `1E-20`.

Comment: Yes, that would cause the problem, definitely.  There's one other really serious bug - namely that each `||` in isTriangle should be `&&` - but the bug you discovered is the one that has the symptom that the OP describes.

Comment: This seems to make it work correctly for the simple cases I tried just now `(3,4,5)` and `(2,2,2)`. I agree that the double comparison will probably break if real floats are entered though.

Comment: I had side1 = sideA before but lost my file and copied someone elses code who was working with me and didn't realize he had it backwards and for || instead of && it was just experimental to see if the output changes and forgot to change it back. what does Math.abs mean and why use epsilon? Is there a way to attach and post a pdf so you can see what the assignment is?

Comment: @user3440443, `Math.abs` is the absolute value function. Instead of direct comparison, we take the absolute value of a difference and check whether it is smaller than some very small number because computers are not precise when computing and comparing decimals (ie floating point numbers).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the input. It works well and produces the same output for the values listed in the assignment that we were supposed to test.